# Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required trying to install packages written in c

Tags: python, c++, windows, pip

Hi I am trying to install the package 'pyfolio' but I get the error indicating:

```
 Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools"
```

but I have already installed visual c++ redist packages but it still does not work.
I found out that the error occurs while installing package `bottleneck`so I thought to read the documentation on installing bottleneck, it was written in c and so I installed MinGW but could not be able to set ming as the compiler 
I also installed cython. I am on a windows machine. 
is there any other alternative to applying here?

Comment: The error message is *crystal clear*. You need Visual C++ 14.0 (aka 2015). Either install the full IDE or get the Build Tools only, as indicated in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people suggest going to the Microsoft link and downloading the entire package to build and compile things. But I like using `choco` for things because it's more straightforward. Basically this is an option if you are Linux user and stuck on windows.

I recommend making a virtual environment incase of mistakes and other fun issues.

```
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/Script/Activate # works with git bash
pip install --upgrade setuptools
choco install visualcppbuildtools
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any Visual C++, you only have Redistributable packages. They install run-time libraries that are used to run applications written with VC. But you need Visual C++ compiler! Install [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required